# Entity Framework - Discriminator problem with TPH

Tags: inheritance, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

I am getting `Invalid column name 'Discriminator'` whilst saving a record. (Code First, EF4.1)

I have an entity I wish to track via EF:

```
public class Audit
 public virtual string p1
 public virtual string p2
```

i have a specialism UserAudit, that adds no new virtual properties, it just sets up base ready for audit

```
public class UserAudit : Audit
 public UserAudit() { p1 = someval; }
```

And the config:

```
public class AuditConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Audit>
  {
    public AuditConfiguration()
    {
      ToTable("_AUDIT");
      HasKey(c => c.Id);
      Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("AUDIT_ID");
    }
  }
```

And the repo:

```
public class AuditRepository : IAuditRepository
  {
    public void LogAudit(Audit audit)
    {
      using (var db = new AuditContext())
      {
        db.Audits.Add(audit);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
  }
```

What do i need to do to tell EF to ignore/handle the specialism correctly when i `repo.LogAudit( userAudit );` ?

Answer (score 5):

From the exception message `Invalid column name 'Discriminator'` I would conclude that you didn't let EF 4.1 create the database table `_AUDIT` because otherwise EF would have created a column called `Discriminator` to the table. Perhaps you have an existing database table without such a column. When EF tries to save the entity it wants to store a value representing the concrete type you are saving into the discriminator column - but the column doesn't exist. Hence the exception.

**Edit**

So, you need a discriminator column. You can define your own custom discriminator column like so:

```
public class AuditConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Audit>
{
    public AuditConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("_AUDIT");
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("AUDIT_ID");

        Map<Audit>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue<byte>(0).IsRequired());
        Map<UserAudit>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue<byte>(1).IsRequired());
    }
}
```

This would use a non-nullable `tinyint` column `Type` in the `_AUDIT` table which has value `0` for base `Audit` type objects and value `1` for the derived `UserAudit` type objects.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I Shouldnt have to add a type to my table - indeed I cant. I want EF to ignore UserAudit - it simply has methods that write to the base properties. Don't discriminate, ignore!

Comment: OK, so I do have a column "TypeOfAction". How do i discriminate on multiple values?

Comment: @BobTodd: You can't ignore `UserAudit` in the EF mapping and then add a UserAudit to the `Audits` set. You could only create a helper method which pulls out an `Audit` from a `UserAudit` (basically by copying all properties) and then store this `Audit` object. You would probably also need a method to create an `UserAudit` from an `Audit` object because when you fetch an object from DB, EF will always instantiate an `Audit` and not an `UserAudit`. Another workaround might be to make `Audit` a member in `UserAudit` (composition instead of inheritance) which avoids the copying of properties.

Comment: @BobTodd: "...discriminate on multiple values..." Do you mean that one and the same type can have different values in this column? If yes, I am afraid that this isn't possible. But I am not sure. You better ask this as a separate question to get a well-founded answer. It would interest me too, if there is a way.

Comment: Yes ive asked this, so far tumbleweed....

I have reverted already to a composition - UserAudit no longer inherits, but composes Audit. Never found myself having to un-factor based on limitations of the framework when using NHibernate (and if i did at least i could edit the code). sigh....

Comment: Yeah, just ran into this myself. The magic unicorn is assuming that a derived class (not mentioned anywhere in config, not in same namespace) is important and is requiring a discriminator. Never intended to save the derived class, just building out my domain. Hmmm..

Comment: Ooo! Oo! 

    modelBuilder.Ignore(new [] {typeof (UserAudit)});

Answer (score 1):

@Slauma is absolutely correct and you should use his solution. I'm just adding explanation why this happens.

Inheritance in entities must be modelled in database because when you load the entity from the database, EF must know if it should materialize `Audit` or `UserAudit` instance. By default EF uses something called Table per Hierarchy inheritance where base type and all subtypes are stored in the same table. To support such scenario EF expects additional column in the table called by default Discriminator. This column will be used to differ stored instance - by default it includes names of types.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the non EF model was inheriting from an EF Model. Instead of inheritance, I have copied all the properties to the non EF Model and that was the solution for me.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Before:**

```
public class PersonWithExtraInfo:Person
{
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**After:**

```
public class PersonWithExtraInfo
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```